# iv7 and m7-5 function

Tags: chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

I couldn't quite understand the movement of this progression and the function of both Abm7 and Am7-5 chord in this progression.

> Fm || Abm7 || Cm | Bb | Am7-5

Do they move to minor scale momentarily through Abm7 and Am7-5? or is there another reason for this movement?

it's from a japanese [song](https://youtu.be/FHu6WhvH6vs?t=20)

Comment: Where do you have these chords from? I can’t here this progression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The passage quoted is a prolonged predominant.**

We're in the key of Eb major, of which the `I` chord immediately precedes the chords in question.

`ii (Fm)`, `iv7 (Abm7)` (borrowed from Eb minor), and `vi (Cm)` all serve as predominant chords, easily moved between because of their shared tones.

From `Cm` the remaining chords arise from a chromatically descending bass line, which leads to `Ab` (`IV`, another predominant), the chord immediately following the OP passage.

**Illustration**

`ii`, `IV`, and `vi` can be stacked up as a single chord: `ii9`

```
X:0
T:ii, IV, and vi chords, stacked
K:Eb
M:none
L:1/1
[FAc] [Ace] [ceg] || [FAceg]
```

Incorporating the `iv` chord from minor (i.e., replacing `C` with `Cb`) effectively creates a half-diminished nine chord.

```
X:0
T:ii, iv, and vi chords, stacked
K:Eb
M:none
L:1/1
[FA_c] [A_ce] [_ceg] || [FA_ceg]
```

The bass movement is what creates the remaining chord progression.

```
X:0
T:chromatic descending bass
K:Eb
M:none
L:1/4
%%score (V1 V2)
[V:V1] [eg] [eg] [ceg] [ce]
[V:V2] "_Cm"c "_Eb/Bb"B "_Am7b5"=A "_Ab"_A
```

In a hyper-local interpretation, the `Am7b5` could be viewed as `Bbbm7b5`, which would be `biimb5` relative to `Ab`.

**Abstraction**

```
X:0
T:Abstract harmonic interpretation
K:Eb
M:none
L:1/1
%%score (V1 V2 V3 V4)
[V:V1] [| "_Eb""Eb"[EGB] || "_(Fm9""Fm"[FAc] || "_Fmb9b5""Abm7b5"[A_ce_g] || "_Fm9)""Cm"[ceg]/2 |  "_desc. bass""Cm"[ceg]/2 y y || "_Ab""Ab"[Ace] |]
[V:V2] x x x x/2 =c/8x"Eb/Bb"B/8x"Am7b5"=A/8
[V:V3] x "<("">)"[eg] "<("">)"F
[V:V4] x x x "<("">)"[FA]/2
```

Answer (score 1):

a very common progression: Yesterday (Beatles)

I (ii7b5 V7)/vi

The song is in Eb.

Do you  mean the passage I - ii - iv?

Eb Fm Abm (Abm = minor subdominant)

I don’t think that there’s really an a minor chord in it.

This could be a chromatic passing chord V- bV - IV:

(Bb - Bbb - Ab)

Now I’ve found may be a quite correct chord sheet where you can see after the dominant Bb it goes back to the relative vi (cm) where the bass plays this vibrato on the chromatic tone a  or Bbb which has an ambivalence beeing the root of the secondary dim7 of Bb (= a) or passing tone to Ab (B double flat)

[Chords in C major (Jap. lyrics)](https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/hatsune-miku/hisui-no-machi-town-of-jade-chords-3323051)

Answer (score 1):

My amateur speculation with lots of secondary dominants:

- Fm Abm7 Cm might be iv-V-i in C minor (Abm7 is similar to G7)
- I think Bb should be Eb (inversion), I don't hear a D natural in the chord
- Cm Eb Am7b5 might be ii-V in Bb (Am7b5 is similar to F7, and you can think of the Bb note in the Eb chord as just a passing tone from the C in Cm to the A in F7)
- So overall, it is iv-V-i in C minor, then the unresolved ii-V in Bb, then IV-V-I in the subsequent Ab Bb Eb.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a move to minor, just temporarily borrowing the G-Flat. The whole sequence functions as predominant. In order the chord sequence functionality is:

1. The first chord Fm11 (diatonic minor ii-11)
2. The second chord Abm9 is a borrowed iv-9 from the parallel minor.
3. Move to vi (Cm) is a bit unexpected, but it continues the pattern of jumping up a third in the bass, while other notes either hold in place or shift by a half step. Resolution to I or V would be more common immediately following the previous two chords.
4. Bb in the bass is not the root, it's a I-64 formed by a bass passing tone
5. Bass drops to A-Natural, now forming half-diminished, which is still a predominant. (it's vii°-7 of V)
6. Ab major chord, diatonic IV